# django-tastypie with django-taggit

Tags: django, tastypie, django-taggit

I am using [django-taggit](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for tagging. I have django-tastypie REST resource for the same object.

While exposing the REST resource, it doesn't fetch the tag field(e.g. equivalent to model.tags.all()).

Is there anything special needs to be done?

I wanted to perform GET and POST operation on object model and retrieve and insert the tags.

Can some one please point to the sample setup to return the tag objects? I have referred to gist [here](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tests/related_resource/api/resources.py), however not able to understand that how you can retrieve associated tags when querying model.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make a `TagResource` :

```
from taggit.models import Tag

class TagResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Tag.objects.all()
```

Then in your resource that got tags:

```
class FooResource(ModelResource):

    tags = fields.ToManyField(TagResource, 'tags', # if your tag field is 'tags'
                              full = True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Foo.objects.all()
```

It should work.

**UPDATE**

In order to filter the tag, you have to filter it through `TagResource`, assuming your api name is `v1`, the url is :

`/api/v1/tag/?slug=anytagyouwant&format=json`

Above url is for like : 'is `anytagyouwant` exist?'

for 'get all foo that have `anytagyouwant` tag'

`/api/v1/foo/?tags__slug=anytagyouwant&format=json`

Note, to be able to filter for certain fields, you have to declare it in your resource, using `FooResource` as an example :

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource, ALL, ALL_WITH_RELATIONS

class FooResource(ModelResource):

    tags = fields.ToManyField(TagResource, 'tags', # if your tag field is 'tags'
                              full = True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Foo.objects.all()
        filtering = dict(
            tags = ALL,
            # or 
            tags = ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        )
```

Comment: For your first URL you will need to add filtering in TagResource - filtering = {
   'slug': ALL,
  } And that also return the tags object, not Foo object. I am trying where I can get all the Foo objects mapped with 'anytagyouwant' tag

Comment: I think your second url is for 'get all the items that have anythingyouwant tag' e.g. api/v1/Foo/?format=json&tags__name=anythingyouwant It works fine.

Comment: Do you know if I can add tag to existing record. e.g. a.tags.all() returns one tag <test>, and I would like to add one more tag so I tried a.tags.add('test2'), though this call fails with (1062, "Duplicate entry '1788' for key 'PRIMARY'")

Comment: Yes you can, but that's odd, that should do fine, even if you add a duplicate tags. I don't know, delete your database and then syncdb again(?)

Comment: If I am using tags with multiple object like Foo, Moo does it change anything? or I can use the tags as ToManyField in Moo as well?

Comment: You mean Foo and Moo got its own tag field? If so, yes, it doesn't change anything, and you can use it as ToManyFieldin Moo

Comment: You are the golden god